# Top 5 comments from a specific post. How to write my SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I want to show only the top 5 comments for a specific post (Like the post on facebook where people cant comment them).

gbn was kind enough to help figure out that issue by doing the following:

```
select
   *
FROM
   tblPost P
   OUTER APPLY
   (SELECT TOP 5 * FROM tblComment C  
      WHERE P.id = C.postid
      ORDER BY something) inline
```

But since I'm no sql grand master I would need your help to put that into my real sql statement.

```
SELECT *
FROM
memberactions INNER JOIN
actions ON memberactions.actionid = actions.id INNER JOIN
members ON memberactions.memberid = members.id LEFT OUTER JOIN
members members_2 INNER JOIN
actioncomments ON members_2.id = actioncomments.memberid INNER JOIN
comments ON actioncomments.commentid = comments.id ON actions.id = actioncomments.actionid
```

So my question is could you rearrange my sql to put the OUTER APPLY in my real sql statement.

Assuming that my table comments reprensent tblComment and that actioncomments represent the table tblPost

[image]

Comment: What RDMS is this for (MySql, Sql Server, Oracle, etc)?

Comment: Probably SQL 2008 based on the [last post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4878516/119477)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There does not seem to be a need for the member_2 table at all, but this is a faithful representation of what you had (preserving member_2)

```
SELECT *
FROM memberactions
INNER JOIN actions
    ON memberactions.actionid = actions.id
INNER JOIN members
    ON memberactions.memberid = members.id
OUTER APPLY (
    select top(5) *
    FROM actioncomments
    inner join comments ON actioncomments.commentid = comments.id
    inner join members members_2 ON members_2.id = actioncomments.memberid
    WHERE actions.id = actioncomments.actionid
    order by comments.id desc) comments
```

Comment: Tried it but still get all the comments

Comment: I get The column 'id' was specified multiple times for 'comments'

Comment: @Yannick - what columns do you `really` need from the inner query, just `comments.*`? List those specifically next to the top(5) in the OUTER APPLY inner query (replacing the *)

Comment: Ok I did that but know I get "Data provider or other service returned and E-FAIL status"  -- Sorry for all the trouble, really appreciated.

Comment: @Yannick - you should try it in SSMS. If that works, then you need to hunt elsewhere for the cause of the error in the front-end layer.

Comment: I get the following in SSMS : Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'memberactions'.

Comment: @Yannick do you have the right database selected? The table name is from your question itself! `select top 10 * from memberactions` - what does this give?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM
memberactions 
INNER JOIN actions 
ON memberactions.actionid = actions.id 
INNER JOIN members 
ON memberactions.memberid = members.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN members members_2 
    INNER JOIN actioncomments 
    ON members_2.id = actioncomments.memberid 
    OUTER APPLY  

    (SELECT TOP 5 * FROM comments C  
          WHERE actioncomments.commentid = comments.id 
      ORDER BY something)


ON actions.id = actioncomments.actioni
```

still don't know what you want to order by

Comment: I removed the order by but I get "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'"